# CSS3 animation not running in Chrome on MY site

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass

I'm trying to animate an SVG with CSS3. You can see an example here -

http://codepen.io/MyXoToD/pen/vBlfs

However this example works exactly as it should in Chrome, however when I implement the code on my site, it doesn't run the code. Yet it works perfectly fine in Firefox. When i Inspect element in Chrome it's putting a line through the animation properties and displaying an error saying 'Invalid property value'. Yet when I look at the example I do the same thing and I don't get the same error.

I'm a little confused and I've been debugging this for a while. It can't be my version of Chrome (which is Version 39.0.2171.95 m).

Although my code is almost exactly the same after some small modifications, here is my snippet:

```
img {
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  //position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: show;
  animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

svg {
  max-width: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  //position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  path {
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke: black;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-name: draw;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    &.bird {
      stroke: black;
      stroke-dasharray: 2810;
      stroke-dashoffset: 2810;

    }

  }
}


}

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes show {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: codepen uses default prefix add -webkit- in you code

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. You saying it could well be the version of Chrome then?

Comment: Seems to be working, not very smoothly. But it's doing something. Thank you.

Comment: You did notice that you've enabled a prefixer on Codepen, right?

Comment: @JoshDavies Yes, all versions of Chrome still require prefixes for that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've enabled the -prefix-free mode on Codepen. It lets you use only unprefixed CSS properties everywhere. It works behind the scenes, adding the current browser’s prefix to any CSS code, only when it’s needed.

For example, on Codepen you will see:

```
animation-name: show;
```

instead of:

```
animation-name: show;
-webkit-animation-name: show;
-moz-animation-name: show;
```

Comment: Thank you! Good to know as mentioned before I had not really used Codepen.